# How to do a callback operation on Sqlite using java?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, callback

I am working on sqlite in Java. Presently I am using [Xerial JDBC Driver.](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads)

I am able to establish connection with an existing DB and perform basic DB operations on it.
But now I have a requirement where callback should happen on CRUD operations performed on DB.

I searched and found that SQLite provides [***Data Change Notification Callbacks***](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/update_hook.html) but these callbacks are in C programming language.

How may I do something equivalent to it in Java using [Xerial JDBC Driver.](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads)? If its not possible using Xerial Driver then I welcome any other suggestion which will enable this feature of callback.